# Generate MySQL documentation

Tags: windows-7, software-development, database, mysql

In Netbeans, if I place comments above all my methods:

[image: Example method with comment]

and then right click on my project and click generate Javadoc:

[image: Context menu: Generate Javadoc]

What gets generated is an HTML document containing the API with the method comments:

[image: "Method Detail", showing the method name and its comment]

This is really useful when working in an agile environment where transparency is so appreciated.

---

I know that in MySQL you can place comments in a similar fashion, for tables:

[image: Entering comment for a MySQL table]

For stored procedures:

[image: Comment for a stored procedure]

and for all other database components.

My question is, is there software that is compatible with Windows 7 that can do what Netbeans does to a Java application except to a MySQL database?

Comment: I never tried it with MySQL: [HyperSQL](https://github.com/IzzySoft/HyperSQL) was written for Oracle, but might be worth a try.

Comment: @Izzy: This should be an answer, surely?

Comment: Being written for Oracle (and I've tested it only with that), I was not sure whether it meets your requirements. If you confirm it's an acceptable solution for you and works with your MySQL code, I happily make it an answer!

Comment: @Izzy: Do you know if it works with windows 7?

Comment: It requires Python, which is available cross-platform. I've been using it on miscellaneous Linux machines (SuSE, Ubuntu), but never on Windows – though I see no specific reason why it shouldn't work there. As it's free (and even open-source), why not simply give it a try? It's setup is as easy as unpacking it and changing into its directory, with some optional adjustments to the `.ini` file.

Comment: Your screen-shot of the table definition looks like it was taken from MySqlWorkbench. If so, the comment is local to that only. It does not appear anywhere in your database (as, for instance does the comment in the stored procedure). AFAIK, MySql does not support storing comments on the tables of a database, so you might want to edit your question. Unless, of course, this documentation generation can be done by MySqlWorkbench - which I doubt, but you could feature request the developers. This is a good question and I will use the solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [sqlDoxygen](https://github.com/paulpster/sqlDoxygen)

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is a well-known standard tool for creating source code documentation. Unfortunately, it does not natively support SQL.  sqlDoxygen is a branch of doxygen with SQL parsing added.

Features:

- Converts comments into HTML, XML, or LaTeX documentation for the source code
- Supports HTML, Markdown, and other special commands in the comments
- Has detailed [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html)

I've only used it with C++ and Fortran, but I assume that it should generate similar results in SQL. The repository also has [a couple test files](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html) that show which format should be used.

Comment: Do you know how one can install sqlDoxygen? I downloaded doxygen for win32 and installed it but I got no idea how to add sqlDoxygen to it?

Comment: @ThreaT I think you could clone the repository ``git clone git@github.com:paulpster/sqlDoxygen.git``, then use the ``winbuild`` folder to build the source. I will try it later today and update the answer with instructions

Comment: It's not immediately clear - is this connecting to a MySql database and generating output from there? Or is it scanning source code which manipulates a database?

Comment: @Mawg Doxygen scans the source code for documentation blocks. It's easier to start with the [manual of the original Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html#cppblock). Example files for sqlDoxygen are found in the [examples folder](https://github.com/paulpster/sqlDoxygen/tree/master/examples). Otherwise, it should work the same way as Doxygen does

Comment: @Threat did you ever try this? did you get an answer?